# Maven Build Failure, Failed to launch Flash Player. Probably java was not able to find flashplayer

Tags: java, maven, flash

I am trying to build my maven project on Ubuntu 12.04, and it returned the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.8:test-run (default-test-run) on project as3-remote: Failed to launch Flash Player.  Probably java was not able to find flashplayer.
[ERROR] Make sure flashplayer is available on PATH
[ERROR] or use -DflashPlayer.command=${flashplayer executable}
[ERROR] Read more at: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Running+unit+tests: Cannot run program "/home/rams/dev/trex-new/as3-remote/target/lib/flashplayer": error=2, No such file or directory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :as3-remote

---

How would I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined in the Read more... link above?

Comment: Yes I have, I forgot to include a more detailed response. I installed the flash player and its still complaining. I think I just need to know where the path to the flash executable is inside of Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Try to run flashplayer in shell. In my case ld-linux.so library was missing.
If so, you need glibc to be installed.
"sudo yum install glibc.i686" works for CentOS 64 bit.